# Class can't load the properties image(s)

Tags: c#, image

My C# class can't find the images I've put in the properties.
I've made a class called **Dice** and a button(**btn_Roll_Dice**) on the **Main_Form** form that calls the function.

I've placed a **Console.WriteLine(Throw);** in the code to check the output. It generates a random number like it should but the images don't show up...

My **Dice** class code:

```
class Dice
{
    public Image[] diceImages;
    public Button[] dice_Stones;
    public int[] Throw = new int[5];
    public Random rand;

    public void RollDice()
    {
        main_Form form1 = new main_Form();

        dice_Stones = new Button[5];
        dice_Stones[0] = form1.btn_Dice1;
        dice_Stones[1] = form1.btn_Dice2;
        dice_Stones[2] = form1.btn_Dice3;
        dice_Stones[3] = form1.btn_Dice4;
        dice_Stones[4] = form1.btn_Dice5;

        diceImages = new Image[6];
        diceImages[0] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_1;
        diceImages[1] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_2;
        diceImages[2] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_3;
        diceImages[3] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_4;
        diceImages[4] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_5;
        diceImages[5] = Properties.Resources.Dobbelsteen_6;

        rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < dice_Stones.Length; i++)
        {
            int Throw = rand.Next(0, 5);
            dice_Stones[i].Image = diceImages[Throw];
        }
    }
}
```

My **btn_Roll_Dice** Button class code:

```
private void btn_Roll_Dice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dice dice = new Dice();
    dice.RollDice();
}
```

Comment: Because you are creating a new form instead of using the existing one, you should pass the form to the dice class and modify the existing instance.

Comment: tbh: why not give a single dice-roll and set the images in the form itself instead. This seems overly complicated and coupled IMO